# Insertar matriz dentro de otra matriz con saltos intermedios

Tags: python, numpy, indices, matriz

Supongamos que tengo dos matrices, A y B:

```
A = [0  1   2   3   4   5   6   7
     8  9   10  11  12  13  14  15
    16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23
    24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31
    32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39
    40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47
    48  49  50  51  52  53  54  55
    56  57  58  59  60  61  62  63]

B = [-1 -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1
     -1 -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1
     -1 -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1
     -1 -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1
     -1 -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1
     -1 -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1
     -1 -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1
     -1 -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1
     -1 -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1
     -1 -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1
     -1 -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1
     -1 -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1]
```

Y quiero introducir A en B para que quede de la siguiente forma:

```
C = [-1 -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1
     -1  0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7  -1
     -1  8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  -1
     -1 16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  -1
     -1 24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  -1
     -1 -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1
     -1 -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1
     -1 32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39  -1
     -1 40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  -1
     -1 48  49  50  51  52  53  54  55  -1
     -1 56  57  58  59  60  61  62  63  -1
     -1 -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1]
```

Como se puede apreciar, la matriz A se ha partido en dos y se han introducido sus dos mitades en posiciones distintas. Es posible lograr esto mediante indexamiento o alguna función de numpy?? La idea es ahorrar bucles.

Answer (score 2):

Suponiendo que ambos arrays son matrices de `8 x 8` y `12 X 10`  respectivamente:

```
import numpy as np


A = np.arange(0,  64).reshape((8, 8))
B = np.full((12, 10), -1)
```

> ```
> >>> A
> array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7],
>        [ 8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
>        [16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23],
>        [24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31],
>        [32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39],
>        [40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47],
>        [48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55],
>        [56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63]])
> >>> B
> array([[-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
>        [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
>        [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
>        [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
>        [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
>        [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
>        [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
>        [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
>        [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
>        [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
>        [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
>        [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1]])
> ```

lo puedes hacer mediante slicing sin problemas, por ejemplo:

```
C = B.copy()
C[1: 5, 1: -1] = A[ :4].copy()
C[-5: -1, 1: -1] = A[4: ].copy()
```

o podría usar `numpy.r_`, aunque no está pensado estrictamente para ello:

```
C = B.copy()
C[np.r_[1:5, -5:-1], 1:-1] =  A
```

> ```
> >>> C
> array([[-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
>        [-1,  0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7, -1],
>        [-1,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, -1],
>        [-1, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, -1],
>        [-1, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, -1],
>        [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
>        [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
>        [-1, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, -1],
>        [-1, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, -1],
>        [-1, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, -1],
>        [-1, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, -1],
>        [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1]])
> ```

En vez de harcodear los índices, podemos calcularlos, pero dependerá de dónde quieras insertar exactamente.